# ClickOnce won't run - Getting 'Specified Cast Not Valid'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, windows-8.1

I have a C# app that we deploy on Win7 machines (using ClickOnce) without any issues (for years now) but we have a few employees with a Surface Pro 2 (8.1) and the app won't install.  When they run the setup.exe they get the standard "contact your administrator for details" error.  Here's the log that it produces:

```
    PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34014
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file://asc-server/public/Programs/Installs/SCS/SCS.application
    Deployment Provider url     : file://asc-server/public/Programs/Installs/SCS/SCS.application
    Application url         : file://asc-server/public/Programs/Installs/SCS/Application%20Files/SCS_3_4_0_9/SCS.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : SCS.application, Version=3.4.0.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc0fb6e85ade2b56, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of \\asc-server\public\Programs\Installs\SCS\SCS.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Specified cast is not valid.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [6/18/2014 8:19:42 AM] : Activation of \\asc-server\public\Programs\Installs\SCS\SCS.application has started.
    * [6/18/2014 8:19:42 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [6/18/2014 8:19:42 AM] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [6/18/2014 8:19:42 AM] System.InvalidCastException
        - Specified cast is not valid.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I see that it says "Specified Cast is not Valid" but I'm not too sure why we're getting that error.  I've tried the following so far (with no luck):

1. Changed Target CPU from x86 to Any CPU
2. Changed signing from sha1RSA to sha256RSA
3. Ran setup.exe as Administrator
4. Turned off all UAC
5. Created a basic windows form (1 form, 1 button) and tried to install, but getting same error.
6. **Latest** - I took the .exe from the basic windows form app and ran it on the Surface Pro, which it runs fine, so I'm thinking it must be a setting issue.

At this point I'm thinking it's a setting either with the Surface Pro OR a VS deployment setting that I'm missing.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This was caused because of the Users security settings.

[image: security settings]

if you select it as in the picture problem is solved automatically. and you may continue installing.

if you cannot see the picture in the link above;

open Control Panel -> User Account Control Settings

adjust the slider 2nd from top. (Notify me only when the apps try to make changes to my computer (default)